# Unable to return json values retrieved from MongoDB to HTML page in python flask

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, pymongo

I'm able to retrieve required value from MongoDB individually and also able to print same values but unable to return all those values to HTML page. When I try to return those values I'm able to see only first value though I have used for loop in jinja. 
My code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/webhookdisplay', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhooksdis():
    collection10 = db['webhooks']
    a = collection10.find({"name": "abc"}, {'_id': 0, 'recorded_at':0, 'expiry_time': 0, 'version': 0, 'created_at': 0, 'account_id': 0, 'device_id': 0})
    for i in collection10.find({}):
        d = i.get('data', {}).get('geometry', {}).get('coordinates')
        print(d)
        name = i.get('data', {}).get('geofence_metadata', {}).get('name')
        print(name)
    return render_template("webhooks.html",  name = name, a = a, d =d)
```

In the above code name has None values also, so when I try to return it individually shows TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Suppose if I return those values which dowsn't have None values it gets returned but displays only first value.
**HTML code**

```
{% for i in d %}
{{ i }} 
{% endfor %}<br />
```

This jinja works for all values but I require for individual values which I'm retrieving in flask:

```
<table>   
<th>           
{% for item in a %} 
</th>
<tr>
<td><th>   {% for key, value in item.items() %} </th>  </td>
<td><span>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</span> </td>
<br />
<td>{% endfor %}</td>
<td>{% endfor %}</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

**Expected Output** All values including None values should be returned which I'm retrieving in flask so that I can render in HTML page

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of:

```
print(request.data)
print(request.form)
print(request.json)
print(request.get_json())
```

?

**UPDATE:**

`a` is a list.  So try:

```
{% for item in a %} 
    {% for key, value in item.items() %}        
        <span>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</span><br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: request.data:  b'[\r\n  {\r\n   "Language" : "python"\r\n  }\r\n]'
request.form:  ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.json:  [{'Language': 'python'}]
request.get_json(): [{'Language': 'python'}]
This is the output I'm getting @GAEfan

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. In postman response I'm able to see entire HTMlL code including JSON values, but in server HTML page I'm getting error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) for template rendering.

Using below pseudo code you can populate JSON data:

```
{% for key, value in a %}        
  <span>{{key}} : {{value}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

```py
if a:   
    filtered_data=[{"name":device["name"]} for device in a]  
    print(filtered_data) 
else:   
    print("Document does not exist !")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help